# Gradle: error: illegal unicode escape

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I recently updated to the most recent Android Studio version (0.2.x), and I am experiencing an issue where I cannot build the project. I receive an error message stating:

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':TestApplication:compileDebug'.
```

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.  C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\TestApplicationProject\TestApplication\build\source\r\debug\com\example\testapplication\R.java

```
Gradle: error: illegal unicode escape
```

Now, I understand I was supposed to reinstall Android Studio as per instructions:

```
Windows users: Do not install Android Studio 0.2.x in the same location as 0.1.x. 
Doing so may cause errors such as ClassCastException or other unexpected behaviors.
It's best if you remove your previous version of Android Studio 0.1.x.
```

And I actually did, I uninstalled Android Studio, and deleted the remaining folder (Which is apparently not deleted after uninstall) stored at: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android`

I then proceeded to clean the registry entry just in case (I tried this on my 3rd attempt after not getting it to work), and rebooted before re-installing.

After the PC rebooted, I proceeded to do a fresh install of Android Studio, it installed successfully. I created a Test Project from scratch (to make sure it was not a problem with opening previous projects), but right after it opened the project it's already showing the build problems. I tried running it and it simply won't compile.

What's even more strange is that **all** of the problematic lines according to the compiler output are **commented** lines in the R.java. Here's one:

```
        /**  From: C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\TestApplicationProject\TestApplication\src\main\res\values\dimens.xml
```

And it points to the character 30 of that line, which is right between the **u** and the **s** of the word **user** ([image attached](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19146514/illegal-unicode-escape.png)). I actually tried deleting the comments, but as you'd expect the R.java was generated automatically when I asked for the project to be rebuilt.

I have absolutely no clue what the problem is, any ideas?

Comment: same here. After I updated 0.1.9 to 0.2.0 I couldn't create new projects so I had to uninstall and re-install and now I get the same error you get.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, but even on the command line build, which to me indicates that the problem is not related to version of the IDE, but the version of the gradle android plugin. For now, I've reverted to the previous version of the plugin I was using (0.4.2) and I'm depending on the command line for builds. I haven't put this as an answer as it's only a workaround until one of the Gradle team picks up on this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Known issue. We have fixed it internally already. Should have it out very soon (couple of days max)

Comment: Workaround found! :)

It wasn't a folder name starting with a 'u'. It was a resource file starting with a  'u'. I have a file called 'res/values/urls.xml' that contains OEM-specific URLs. I changed the name to 'string_urls.xml' and now all is well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was using a path similar to yours.

What I did was **move the project to the root of the C drive**, so the path doesn't start with "C:\Users\user" anymore and the problem is avoided... Not really a solution, but a workaround.

PS: This is not really an answer, but I don't have enough points to comment yet and this might help someone.